# Which activityType is better for using?

Tags: cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have an app that can be used for driving, skiing, walking, train, etc.  Which `activityType` should be used?  Will `CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation` cover all usecases?

Code is to cater for iOS 8 and 9 - (have a niggling doubt that the `respondsToSelector` should be removed):

```
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
{
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
}

if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)])
{
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;
}
```